# What does$|z|^{2} +βz+\bar{β}\bar{z}+γ =0$ represent if $|β|^{2}≥ γ$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

What does$|z|^{2} +βz+\bar{β}\bar{z}+γ =0$ represent if $|β|^{2}≥ γ$?

I have expanded the equation $|z|^{2} +βz+\bar{β}\bar{z}+γ =0$ using $z=x+iy$. I got the equation $x^{2} +y^{2} + 2Re(βz)+γ =0$. How to proceed further? Please help me.

Comment: If $\beta = b_1 + b_2i$, the equation will become $x^2+y^2 + 2b_1x - 2b_2y +\gamma = 0$. Now can you see that this is a circle with center $(-b_1, b_2)$ and radius $|\beta|^2 - \gamma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(z + \overline{\beta})(\overline{z} + \beta) - \beta \overline{\beta} + \gamma = |z + \overline{\beta}|^2 - |\beta|^2 + \gamma$$

$ \left|z + \overline{\beta}\right|^2 = |\beta|^2 - \gamma$ is the equation of a circle centred at $-\overline{\beta}$, with radius $\sqrt{|\beta|^2 - \gamma}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
|z|^{2} +\beta z+\bar{\beta}\bar{z}+\color{red}{|\beta|^2-|\beta|^2}+ \gamma =0 \;\;&\iff\;\; (z+\bar\beta)(\bar z + \beta)=|\beta|^2-\gamma \\
 &\iff\;\; |z+\bar \beta|^2=|\beta|^2-\gamma
\end{align}
$$